# SQL FileTable GetFileNamespacePath

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob, filetable

I am using Filetable in SQL 2016. let's take a look at some select commands below:

1.

```
  Select [stream_id] from <FileTable>
```

2.

```
Select [stream_id], [name] from <FileTable> with (nolock)
```

3.

```
Select [Stream_id], [name], file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath(0) as ntfsPath from <FileTable> with (nolock)
```

I must use `with(nolock)`. **if some one has opened a file such as a word document and I don't use 'NOLOCK', SQL returns only some records and then caught in a specific record and wouldn't return any records afterward**. However number 1 and 2 return result but number 3 does not because of `file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath(0)`. If I omit `file_stream.GetFileNamespacePath(0)` then SQL returns a result. Whats the problem with `GetFileNamespacePath()`?
Do I missed something in filestream configuration or use of `Select` command ?

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what your actual question is here.

Comment: 3rd query does not return result. what's the problem ?

Comment: How could anybody know? We can't see your screen or read your mind.